# How can I eliminate repeating elements (including itself) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Here is the example.

Input:

```
var nums = [2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6]
```

I want output =[4,6].

I'm rookie, and I try to use another array to `deposit[4,6]`, but I've tried my best:

```
     var nums = [2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6],
        temp = [],
        index = -1;
    for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        target = nums[i];
        for (var j = i + 1; j < nums.length; j++) {
            if (target == nums[j]) {
                target = nums[i + 1];
                break;
            }
            else {
                index++;
                temp[index] = nums[i];
            }
        }
        console.log(temp[index]);
    }
```

No idea.

I know how to eliminate repeating elements (without itself).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the count of each distinct number into a JavaScript object, then grab all the distinct numbers whose count is exactly 1, like:

```js
// Defines the original array, the counts object, and the final array
const
  nums = [2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6],
  counts = {},
  unmatched = [];

// Object properties are key/value pairs. If the key doesn't exist, creates
//   it with a value of 1; or if it already exists, increments the value.
for(let num of nums){
  if(counts[num] === undefined){
    counts[num] = 1;
  }
  else{
    ++counts[num];
  }
}

// Shows the intermediate object
console.log("Counts of unique numbers:")
console.log(counts);


// The [Object.keys][1] method gives the objects' (own, enumerable, string) keys
const distinctNums = Object.keys(counts);

// For each key, we decide whether it belongs in the final array
for(distinctNum of distinctNums){
  if(counts[distinctNum] === 1){
    unmatched.push(distinctNum);
  }
}

// Shows the final array
console.log("Unmatched numbers:");
console.log(unmatched);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height:100% !important; top:0; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your patience,I haven't learned the functions in JS yet(i know C# better than js ，js rookie totally...)Just now I spent a lot of time to have a preliminary understanding in the functions in js...i failed...i need to learn more about js...u're kindful,thank u for ur annotation...other friends have good answers as well,thx everyone.

Comment: Everyone's a rookie at first. If you're going to be writing a lot of JavaScript, **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)** will be a good friend and can teach you almost everything you need to know. (Some people also like [Eloquent JavaScript](https://eloquentjavascript.net/) or [javascript.info](https://javascript.info/intro) .)

Comment: Btw, the answers using [Sets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and the built-in Array methods (like [.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)) offer more elegant ways to handle this kind of task once you're more comfortable, but you'll likely be using "plain old JavaScript objects" a lot, so it might be worth gaining familiarity with them first.

Answer (score 1):

On a sorted array one could filter out all elements wo are either equal the item before or after them:

```
const result = nums.filter((it, i) => 
   (!i || it !== nums[i - 1]) && 
   (i + 1 === nums.length || it !== nums[i + 1])
 );
```

Comment: Well yes, but what about an unsorted array?

Comment: sort it first maybe? Conveniently, the array given by the OP is already sorted.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `Set` of elements (so they contain all unique elements) , and use a for loop to get the count of each element, and remove them, if their count isn't 1.

```js
var nums = [2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6];

let set = [...new Set(nums)];

for(var i = 0; i < set.length; i++){

  let count = nums.filter(x=> x == set[i]).length
  if(count !== 1){
    nums.splice(nums.indexOf(set[i]), count);
  }
}
console.log(nums)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first create a dictionary using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and then select only the elements that don't repeat.

```js
var nums = [2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6];
const dict = nums.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (acc[curr]) ++acc[curr];
  else acc[curr] = 1;
  return acc;
}, {});

const result = [];
for (let key in dict) {
  if (dict[key] === 1) {
    result.push(+key);
  }
}

console.log(result);
```